# Search function data entry form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With some help from here i've made a data form, whereby data is put from an input sheet to a data sheet and then the input sheet is emptied again.
Now I want to be able to find the data back in the input sheet when I put the right code.
How do I do this?

This is the script to put data from the input sheet towards the data sheet.

```
function Process() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NIEUW Invoerbestand');
  const inputSheet =ss.getSheetByName('Input')
  const idCell = ss.getRangeByName('Barcode');
  const id = idCell.getValue();
  const cellFound = dataSheet.getRange('A:A')
    .createTextFinder(id)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findNext()
  if (!cellFound) return;
  const fieldRange = inputSheet.getRange('Input!E4:E231');
  const fieldValues = [fieldRange.getValues().flat()];
  dataSheet
    .getRange(cellFound.getRow(), 6)
    .offset(0, 0, fieldValues.length, fieldValues[0].length)
    .setValues(fieldValues);
  fieldRange.clearContent();
  idCell.clearContent();
}
```

I've tried this script, but this gives the error 'forEach is not a function'

```
const searchCell = inputSheet.getRange ("B2")
const searchValue = searchCell.getValue()
const data = dataSheet.getRange ("A4:HY").getValues()
const recordsFound = data.filter( r => r[0] == searchValue)
if(recordsFound.lenght === 0) return

fieldRange.forEach ((f,i) => inputSheet.getRange(f).setValue(recordsFound[0][i+6]))
}
```

Comment: when you get such error 'forEach is not a function'  which means, fieldRange is not a valid   object. Try to log to see what do you get of this variable.

Comment: This gives me a whole lot of rows like these:
toString: [Function],
  setNumberFormat: [Function],
  getNumberFormat: [Function],
  getFilter: [Function],
  setComment: [Function],
  getComment: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  getValue: [Function],
  isBlank: [Function],
  merge: [Function],
  check: [Function],
  setValue: [Function],
  offset: [Function],
  sort: [Function],

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your 1st and 2nd scripts. Can I ask you about the detail of it and your expected result? If `fieldRange` in the 2nd script is the same with the 1st script, I think that the reason for `I've tried this script, but this gives the error 'forEach is not a function'` is due to that `fieldRange` is Range object. But, I cannot understand your question. So, first, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.